# Is there a way to pre-fill out Read-Host in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that helps a user find if a file hash exists in a folder. After the user has entered the hash I determine what type of hash it is and if it is not supported or if the user missed a letter it will return to asking for a hash. For ease of use I want to be able to pre-fill out what the user had type in the previously so they do not need to start over.

```
while (1)
{
    $hashToFind = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter hash to find or type 'file' for multiple hashes"
    # Check if user wants to use text file
    if ($hashToFind -eq "file" )
    {

        Write-Host "Be aware program will only support one has type at a time. Type is determined by the first hash in the file." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
        $hashPath = New-Object system.windows.forms.openfiledialog
        $hashPath.InitialDirectory = “c:\”
        $hashPath.MultiSelect = $false
        if($hashPath.showdialog() -ne "OK")
        {
            echo "No file was selected. Exiting program."
            Return
        }
        $hashToFind = Get-Content $hashPath.filename
    }

    # Changes string to array
    if ( $hashToFind.GetTypeCode() -eq "String")
    {
        $hashToFind+= " a"
        $hashToFind = $hashToFind.Split(" ")
    }

    if ($hashToFind[0].Length -eq 40){$hashType = "SHA1"; break}
    elseif ($hashToFind[0].Length -eq 64){$hashType = "SHA256"; break}
    elseif ($hashToFind[0].Length -eq 96){$hashType = "SHA384"; break}
    elseif ($hashToFind[0].Length -eq 128){$hashType = "SHA512"; break}
    elseif ($hashToFind[0].Length -eq 32){$hashType = "MD5"; break}
    else {echo "Hash length is not of supported hash type."}
}
```

I am newer to PowerShell so if there are any other comments they are welcome!

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to pre-fill the read-host dialog, however data entered into the prompt IS saved in the command history, so all a user would need to do in order to get back to the previously typed hash would be to hit the 'up' arrow key and they would be able to edit whatever they need to.    However looking over your script you may be better served with [parameter validation](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/05/15/simplify-your-powershell-script-with-parameter-validation/) instead of this while loop

Comment: no way to prefill it, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

From [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1369549/360094):

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("yes")
Read-Host "Your answer"
```

As noted by @jing, the `SendKeys` class kind of simulates keyboard strokes so they will be directed to whatever window that currently holds focus. Therefore, don't rely on it as a reliable way to automate stuff.

Comment: It writes the text into any window which is active at the moment.

Comment: @jing, oh right, I added a warning about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have came up with solution like this:

```
while (1)
    {
        $hashToFind = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter hash to find or type 'file' for multiple hashes. Enter 'R' for reply input"

        if ($hashToFind -eq 'R' -and $PreviousInput)
        {
            $handle = (Get-Process -Id $PID).MainWindowHandle

            $code = {
            param($handle,$PreviousInput)
            Add-Type @"
      using System;
      using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
      public class Tricks {
         [DllImport("user32.dll")]
         [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
         public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
      }
    "@
            [void][Tricks]::SetForegroundWindow($handle)
            Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
            [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($PreviousInput)
            }

            $ps = [PowerShell]::Create()
            [void]$ps.AddScript($code).AddArgument($handle).AddArgument($PreviousInput)
            [void]$ps.BeginInvoke()
        }

        $PreviousInput = $hashToFind

        # Check if user wants to use text file
        if ($hashToFind -eq "file" )
        {
            $PreviousInput = $null

            Write-Host "Be aware program will only support one has type at a time. Type is determined by the first hash in the file." -ForegroundColor Yellow
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
            $hashPath = New-Object system.windows.forms.openfiledialog
            $hashPath.InitialDirectory = “c:\”
            $hashPath.MultiSelect = $false
            if($hashPath.showdialog() -ne "OK")
            {
                echo "No file was selected. Exiting program."
                Return
            }
            $hashToFind = Get-Content $hashPath.filename
        }

        # Changes string to array
        if ( $hashToFind.GetTypeCode() -eq "String")
        {
            $hashToFind+= " a"
            $hashToFind = $hashToFind.Split(" ")
        }

        if ($hashToFind[0].Length -eq 40){$hashType = "SHA1"; break}
        elseif ($hashToFind[0].Length -eq 64){$hashType = "SHA256"; break}
        elseif ($hashToFind[0].Length -eq 96){$hashType = "SHA384"; break}
        elseif ($hashToFind[0].Length -eq 128){$hashType = "SHA512"; break}
        elseif ($hashToFind[0].Length -eq 32){$hashType = "MD5"; break}
        else {echo "Hash length is not of supported hash type."}
    }
```